# How snapshot works in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

If we have a dataset like

```
"user":{
     "A":"1"
     "B":"2"
     "C":"3"
     ...
}
```

When we call in Swift:

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"something/user")
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value)
})
```

We can see snapshot has all data from the database. Does snapshot dynamically call each data from Firebase to give the value? Or it fetched all data at once and saved in local?
In another word, could we have a way only fetch partial data (like only A,B and if we call it again, snapshot will fetch C,D) from the Firebase? Do we only have no choice but to fetch the flatten data at once?

Comment: The question is a tad unclear but if you are asking if you can read in values one at a time, the answer is yes. .childAdded reads in each child one at a time and will then fire any time a new child is added. Also if you know the specific path to the data, you can read in that one node. For example; a list of users and the key's are their first name and values are their last name (this is a *bad* idea but using it for clarity) and wanted to know what user bob's value is. The ref is let ref = Firebase(url:"user/bob"). Your snapshot would contain the key of bob and the value of their last name.

Comment: @Jay, I apologize about that it is unclear to you. However, what I mean is not reading data when dataset gets change or has new data come in. What I ask is suppose we have one large scale dataset. Could we read it partially to save some traffic of network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call:

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value
```

You're registering to monitor the value of the location in the database. Initially and whenever the value in that location changes, the server sends a snapshot of that value to the client.

In the Firebase database, you can only get complete nodes. There is no way to get a partial node.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ask. But there is another question comes out. Suppose we have a node dataset scales at 10MB, it takes time(probably 10seconds) when front-end try to fetch the data from Firebase, and make user become unpleasant to wait data download. Is there any way to avoid this? Or should I manage back-end to split table sheets from the beginning?

Comment: If your data structure is leading to problems (such as an unpleasant user experience), then you should probably use a different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort data using methods such as queryOrderedByKey, queryOrderedByValue or queryOrderedByChild. Then litmit the number of results by using methods such as queryLimitedToFirst, queryLimitedToLast, queryStartingAtValue, queryEndingAtValue or queryEqualToValue.

More info please read the Firebase documentations at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data